# why initialize array by other, cause other array to change

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have constant array  of week (named "allHours"):

```
export const allHours = [
{ hour: "10:00", key: 0, busy: false },
{ hour: "11:00", key: 1, busy: false },
{ hour: "12:00", key: 2, busy: false },
{ hour: "13:00", key: 3, busy: false },
{ hour: "14:00", key: 4, busy: false },
{ hour: "15:00", key: 5, busy: false },
{ hour: "16:00", key: 6, busy: false },
{ hour: "17:00", key: 7, busy: false },
{ hour: "18:00", key: 8, busy: false },
{ hour: "19:00", key: 9, busy: false },
];
```

and now i want to loop on it and manipulate new array(availableHours) for each iterate,
so after the for loop i put :   let availableHours = [...allHours];

the code is :

```
export const getAvailableMeetings = meetings => {
const finalArray = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {

    let availableHours = [...allHours];///// here i expected to see the
    ///// availableHours array initialize again and all the busy field - initialize to false in each iterate

    const date = moment().add(i, "days");
    meetings.map(meet => {
        if (moment(meet.date).startOf("day").isSame(date.startOf("day"), "days")) {
            console.log("start of iterate", date.startOf("day"), "strartof meetings", moment(meet.date).startOf("day"));
            let busyHour = availableHours.findIndex(i => i.hour === moment(meet.date).format("LT"));
            availableHours[busyHour].busy = true;
        }
    });

    finalArray.push({
        key: i,
        date: date.toISOString(),
        dayName: moment().add(i, "days").format("dddd"),
        hours: date.weekday() === 5 || date.weekday() === 6 ? [] : availableHours,
    });
}

return finalArray;
```

};

regards to the comment in the code,
**i expected for initialize the available hour on each iterate.**
but actually its not, and continue with the filling bust,
when i console log the "allHours" array i see that the busy field changed by the availableHours

**the point here its why the allHours array changed regards to the availableHours array?? **

Comment: This has to do with storing variables by reference vs. storing them by value. Objects are stored by **reference** in memory, and the spread operator only does a **shallow** clone, not a deep one. So while `availableHours` is itself a new array, the objects inside them are the same ones in memory from `allHours`. You can check out articles explaining storing by reference, vs .value, like this one: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of references to objects.  If you copy the array, you have a copy... but each copied element is still a reference to the same object.

You need to do:

```
let availableHours = allHours.map((el) => { ...el });
```

Comment: i put this line in place of : 
let availableHours = [...allHours];

i get  "decleration or statement expected

Comment: ok i add  parenthesis i think its for the return (?)

 let availableHours = allHours.map(el => ({...el}));
work like magic